# Jquery remove hover disruptions on overlapping items

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have an info-graphic I am making interactive. I have created div's which overlap the images to make them clickable and I have created text-boxes that contain the info which will be revealed when the user hovers over the image.

The problem is that when I hover over the image, the text-box disrupts the hover event because it thinks I am no longer hovering over the image.

How make it so the hover will ignore the text-box overlap? 
[**Example on codepen**](http://codepen.io/joshuabutts/pen/pJBbdR)

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.step1').hover(function() {
                $('.step1_info').toggleClass('move1');
            });
            $('.step2').hover(function() {
                $('.step2_info').toggleClass('move1')
            });
            $('.step3').hover(function() {
                $('.step3_info').toggleClass('move2')
            });
            $('.step4').hover(function() {
                $('.step4_info').toggleClass('move2')
            });
            $('.close').hover(function() {
                $(this).parent('div').removeClass('move2').removeClass('move1')
            });

        });
```

HTML

```
    <img src="http://smartcoder.co/wp-content/themes/smartcoder_theme/content/infographic.png" alt="dfgdfg" />

    <div class="clickable step1"><div class="c_area"></div></div>
    <div class="clickable step2"><div class="c_area"></div></div>
    <div class="clickable step3"><div class="c_area"></div></div>
    <div class="clickable step4"><div class="c_area"></div></div>
        <div class="step1_info step_right">You will login to our secure web portal and give us compete access to all your files so we can perform the coding services<p class="close">close</p></div>
        <div class="step2_info step_right">Once we have access to your system, you will be on your way to better codes and our cetified nurses will write the recommendations<p class="close">close</p></div>
        <div class="step3_info step_left">Once the coding has been completed, you can download them again from our secure web portal<p class="close">close</p></div>
        <div class="step4_info step_left">We will review the codes together with you and make sure everything is in order.<p class="close">close</p></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Set `pointer-events: none;` on the text boxes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738984/css-hover-passes-through-elements-to-activate-hover-on-covered-element