# Hover for elements underneath others

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a situation where I want to provide some contextual help with tooltips...However, the elements I have are sometimes underneath an absolute positioned element.

Whilst I realise this is probably impossible I was thinking there was away to interrogate elements underneath the top layered element?

Im just not sure how this would be done.  I dont mind using either css or javascript but any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Please see the image for the absolute positioned div (grey box with red scribble) over the bars underneath.

Please note that the Green bar is position relative while the individual bars are also positioned : absolute.

[image: Absolute Div]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS - Hover passes through elements to activate hover on covered element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738984/css-hover-passes-through-elements-to-activate-hover-on-covered-element)

Comment: Do the elements on the top need to have mouse events?

Comment: No they dont need to

Comment: Also it should be noted that I need support for IE9 and above...pointer-events I dont think is supported here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check for a mouse hit inside each child div; Here's a fiddle for it https://jsfiddle.net/6rx18d56/1. The hit test:

```
function inside(a, x, y) {
  var l = a.offset().left;
  var t = a.offset().top;
  var r = l + a.outerWidth(true);
  var b = t + a.outerHeight(true);

  return l <= x && x <= r && 
         t <= y && y <= b;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Yeah, lol, I knew that was coming. Check out https://jsfiddle.net/6rx18d56/2/. I've made it somewhat more generic, hopefully you have some ID and class names rationale in your charts. Anyways, the hit test being the same, we just loop through elements with jQuery, keeping track of the originating overlay and whether a hit has already ocurred:

```
$(".foo").on("mousemove", function(e) {
  var hit = false;
  var self = $(this);

  $(".x, .y").each(function(ignore, d) {
    if (!hit) {
      if (inside($(d), e.pageX, e.pageY)) {
        self.attr("title", $(d).attr("title"));
        hit = true;
      }
      else {
        self.attr("title", "");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Actually just looking at the js.  I have 400 of these bars on a page and a range of 0 to 15 internal divs of these bars so as you could imagine providing if/else to check every div is not feasible :).

Could you provide some alternative logic that didnt require the if/else logic?

Comment: Legendary!  Made a couple of minor adjustments just to suit my needs.... one of which was just to iterate through the segments part of the same container as the grey container rather than the 4000 segments I have on the page.

I'm sure this is what you wouldve done but you were just illustrating the concept to me!  Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's position, although it will end up being fairly verbose:

`var pos = $("myDiv").position();`

Then determine position by:

`console.log(pos.left, pos.top, pos.right, pos.bottom)`

Read here for more info:

https://api.jquery.com/position/

Then you can check on `.mousemove` if it's within the bounds of the div. Read here:

https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/

However, there's a pretty good chance this isfar too complex for average use.