# How to add progress bar inside a tree structure node or on mouse hover in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my code and I want to put a progress bar inside every node but somehow I am not able to do it as for dynamic tree structure or when a mouse hover on the node it should display its progress bar. I have json file which contain required details.
the numeric progress which is shown in rectangle want to display as progress bar or mouse over action is it possible in D3

```
    body {
    text-align: center;
    }

    svg {
    margin-top: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    }

    .person rect {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    }

    .person {
    font: 14px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    </style>

    <body>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var boxWidth = 150,
    boxHeight = 40;

    // Setup zoom and pan
    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([.1,1])
    .on('zoom', function(){
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ") scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
    })
    // Offset so that first pan and zoom does not jump back to the origin
    .translate([150, 200]);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('width', 1000)
    .attr('height', 500)
    .call(zoom)
    .append('g')
    // Left padding of tree so that the whole root node is on the screen.
    // TODO: find a better way
    .attr("transform", "translate(150,200)");

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .nodeSize([90, 200])
    .separation(function(){
    return .5;
    })
    .children(function(person){
    return person._parents;
    });

    d3.json('data/4gens.json', function(error, json){

    if(error) {
    return console.error(error);
    }

    var nodes = tree.nodes(json),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Style links (edges)
    svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", elbow);

    // Style nodes
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.person")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "person")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    // Draw the rectangle person boxes
    node.append("rect")
    .attr({
    x: -(boxWidth/2),
    y: -(boxHeight/2),
    width: boxWidth,
    height: boxHeight
    });

    // Draw the person's name and position it inside the box
    node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", -(boxWidth/2) + 10)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr('class', 'name')
    .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
    });

    node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", -(boxWidth/2) + 10)
    .attr("dy", 16)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr('class', 'About SPAN')
    .text(function(d) {
    return d.born;
    });

    });


    </script>
```

Comment: I think this is possible by adding a `rect` inside your initial `rect` with its width set to the amount of percentage of the value and `visibility` as `hidden` in CSS, then add a pseudo class in CSS on the parent rect like `.person rect:hover > rect`, which sets `visibility` to `visible`.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable in D3, just add another `rect` after your main rectangle for nodes.

You need to add the rectangle in your D3 code like the following.

```
// Draw the rectangle person boxes
node.append("rect")
  .attr({
    x: -(boxWidth/2),
    y: -(boxHeight/2),
    width: boxWidth,
    height: boxHeight
  });

  // ***** Add the following here *****
  // This assumes your progress bar has boxWidth as its full width,
  // starts from the left, and has the height as the entire box.
  // To change this behavior, adjust the corresponding lines (x, y, width and height).
  node.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'progressBar')
    .attr('x', -(boxWidth/2))
    .attr('y', -(boxHeight/2))
    .attr('width', d => parseInt(d.progress.split('|')[1].trim()) / 100 * boxWidth)
    .attr('height', boxHeight);
```

You can also add styling in your CSS:

```css
.person rect {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
/* ***** Add the following here, adjust as needed ***** */
.person rect.progressBar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

The mouse hovering part is a little bit tricky as you may want to add `:hover` to the `<g>` element. And you'll need to [make pointer events to pass through everything inside the node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738984/css-hover-passes-through-elements-to-activate-hover-on-covered-element) (unless you want to do something fancy to the node itself, this shouldn't be a big issue). Then the CSS part becomes the following:

```css
.person rect {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
/* ***** Add the following here, adjust as needed ***** */
.person rect.progressBar {
  fill: steelblue;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.person * {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.person:hover rect.progressBar {
  visibility: visible;
}}

/** 
 * Also change the following
 * Because if everything in <g> has pointer-events bypassed,
 * it will not trigger hover by default.
 */
.person {
  pointer-events: bounding-box;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Xiaoyi Cao thanks its working fine but progress bar is on the  same rectangle not inside the rectangle as i want the progress bar inside every node

Comment: Since `<rect>` is not nestable, you cannot really put elements within it. However, the prograss bar is represented by a separate `<rect>` element and you can always adjust the size of the progress bar in the first part of the code to make it _appear inside_ every rectangle. For example, you can reduce the `height` value and increase the `y` value, then the progress bar will not fill the entire node, the same thing can be used on `weight` (make it not `* boxWidth`) and `x` to shrink it horizontally.

Comment: Basically I try not to impose my UI design choices on the solution, so the progress bar in the answer is occupying the entire node (if it's at 100%). You may adjust the corresponding lines according to the comments in the first code section to match your design choices.